# Run function after submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in HTML, this form is submitted through a JavaScript function. I want to disable the field when the form is submitted. I tried this but I won't work.

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="my_form" method="GET">
<div class="naam-speeltijd-timer">
<div class="naam-overigetijd">

<div class="settime">
<div class="tekst">selecteer het aantal minuten:</div>
<div class="inputfield"><input type="time" name="usr_time" id="usr_time" /> 
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="settime-activeerbutton">

<div class="submit">
<a href="javascript:postform()" class="button blue"><div class="light">       
</div>start timer</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">     
function postform( )
{
document.getElementById("usr_time").disabled = true;
document.getElementById('my_form').submit() ;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work means? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I'd say that works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sxbgetso/

Comment: Your form needs an action otherwise there is nothing to submit it to: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: The submit action will refresh the page.. so you could use cookies or localStorage for this.

Comment: i checked the fiddle, when i submit the form, i want to disable the input field but the input field doesn't disable

Comment: @sebastiaan, actually the input is being disabled but the page refreshes, that's why I think you are confused. Your code works fine.

Comment: use `ajax` to submit and put an `event.preventDefault()` function after the ajax post. I issue you are facing would probably because of the page refresh after submit()

Comment: @Ionut, But when i type example: 02:00 and submit the form, it runs again, how is this possible if the input field is disabled?

Comment: if you submit the form, then the page is refreshed immediately. Disabling the field just before refreshing is pointless, because all client-side (javascript) changes to the page are lost when you postback/refresh (the web is _stateless_, remember). If you want the field to be disabled _after_ the refresh then your server-side code will have to control that.

Answer (score -1):

The field is actually being deactivated, but when submitting the form, the page is reloaded and returned to its initial state, that is, the field is activated.

You could for simplicity use ajax as other answers suggested.
But if it is not an option, you will need a flag to indicate whether the field should be disabled or not when loading the page. And a button to reset this flag.

Like this:

```
...
<button onClick="reset()">RESET</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if(localStorage.disabled){
    document.getElementById("usr_time").disabled = true;
  }

  function reset(){
    document.getElementById("usr_time").disabled = false;
    localStorage.removeItem('disabled');
  }

  function postform(){
    document.getElementById("usr_time").disabled = true;
    localStorage.disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('my_form').submit() ;
  };
</script>
...
```

Functional example:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so41467628?embed=1&file=index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use onclick rather than href something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="my_form" method="GET">
<div class="naam-speeltijd-timer">
<div class="naam-overigetijd">

<div class="settime">
<div class="tekst">selecteer het aantal minuten:</div>
<div class="inputfield"><input type="time" name="usr_time" id="usr_time" />
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="settime-activeerbutton">

<div class="submit">
<a href="#" onclick="postform(this);" class="button blue"><div class="light">
</div>start timer</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function postform(link)
{
    alert("click");
    link.onclick = function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    document.getElementById('my_form').submit() ;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do this by using an AJAX request. Otherwise, the input field is disabled, but the page is reloaded just afterwards, so you don't see the field being disabled.

```
function postform() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'pageThatProcessesTheRequest.php', // does not have to be .php, can be whatever you use to process the data
        data: $("#usr_time").val()
    }).done(function () {
        $("#usr_time").prop("disabled", "true");
    });
}
```

Also, be sure to have jQuery included with

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or something similar

Comment: add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj the OP want really to submit.

Comment: well, AJAX then. I'll change it briefly

Comment: you can submit through ajax. if page is refreshed, there is no use of disabling the field.